# Color a text string before and after a specific character

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, text

I have some data that can only be sorted in specific ways due to the way it's outputted.

I have a table with such text strings as

```
MyTextString_MyTextString
MyTextString_MyTextString
MyTextString_MyTextString
```

To make it more readable, I'm looking to color the text before `_` red and the text after `_` blue. Is this possible with jquery, or php?

I have tried things such as `$('.myElement').find('_').css('color','red);` but don't think that is the right approach.

Is it possible to only do this once, such as if there is another text string it will remain the second color, blue? i.e. Red_Blue_Blue_Blue (Count = 1?)

Example of markup.

```
<td class="myTextString1">
    MyTextString_MyTextString1
    <br/>
    MyTextString_MyTextString2
    <br/>
    MyTextString_MyTextString3
</p>
```

Comment: Could you show an actual example of the mark-up you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js:

```
var colorize = function(text) {
  var delimiter = "_",
      parts = text.split(delimiter),
      firstPart = $("<span>", { class: 'red', html: parts[0] }),
      secondPart = $("<span>", { class: 'blue', html: text.split(parts[0] + delimiter)[1] });

  return $("<div>").append(firstPart).append(delimiter).append(secondPart).html();
}
```

edit: You could also utilize a helper function that takes jQuery elements like this:

```
var colorizeElements = function($elements) {
  // $elements has to be something like $("td.classname")
  $elements.each(function() {
    $(this).html(colorize($(this).html()));
  });
};
```

edit: working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tGV54/1/

edit: based on Kristoffers code:

```
String.prototype.colorize = function () {
    var regex = new RegExp('[^_]+', 'gi'),
        color = $.extend(['blue', 'red'], arguments || []),
        index = 0;

    return this.replace(regex, function(matched) {
        return '<span style="color: ' + color[index++] + ';">' + matched + '</span>';
    });
};

$.fn.customColorize = function () {
    var args = arguments,
        delimiter = "<br>";

    return this.each(function () {
        var splitetElements = $.map(this.innerHTML.split(delimiter), function(s) { return s.colorize(); });
        this.innerHTML = splitetElements.join(delimiter);
    });
};
```

Comment: How do I assign this to a TD.ClassName? :)

Comment: sry for confusing you... i made a jsFiddle that actually works here http://jsfiddle.net/tGV54/1/ :)

Comment: It's really nice but I need to do it after <br/> (fiddle: jsfiddle.net/gTZH2/6). I know, it's not my mark and I can't control it ;((

Comment: I altered Kristoffers plugin to split by <br> before colorizing the single parts. I renamed the function though (till now it was simple and clean, but now it is somehow unclear from the name what the function exactly would do. I wonder how he would have done it). http://jsfiddle.net/gTZH2/7/

Answer (score 3):

I've done a fiddle to show (in my opinion) a nice way to do this.
[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gTZH2/3/)

There are two plugins, one that extend String.prototype and another one that extends jQuery.fn. By doing this way you call ".colorize()" both from a string and an element. I've included some examples in the fiddle.

```
String.prototype.colorize = function () {
    var regex = new RegExp('[^_]+', 'gi'),
        color = $.extend(['blue', 'red'], arguments || []),
        index = 0;    

    return this.replace(regex, function(matched) {
        return '<span style="color: ' + color[index++] + ';">' + matched + '</span>';
    });
}

$.fn.colorize = function () {
    var args = arguments;

    return this.each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.colorize
            .apply(this.innerHTML, args);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like a really elegant solution. Can we repeat the function after every <br/> or is that not possible? Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/gTZH2/6/

Comment: Yes you can! A simple solution would be to wrap your text in spans. Fiddle -> [jsfiddle.net/gTZH2/11](http://jsfiddle.net/gTZH2/11)

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to the actual markup, its a joke - i know. :[

Comment: Thanks for your time Kristoffer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
$stringParts = explode( '_', 'MyTextString_MyTextString' );
$stringParts[0] = sprintf( '<span style="color: #f00;">%s</span>', $stringParts[0] );
if( count( $stringParts ) > 1 )
{
    $stringParts[1] = sprintf( '<span style="color: #00f;">%s</span>', $stringParts[1] );
    /* …or whatever */
}
echo implode( '_', $stringParts );
```